# VBA | Word <--> Table Column Alignment

Tags: vba, ms-word

got a problem with the right alignment from columns in a word document.
I'm creating a word document with a table from one of our systems. The first time creating the table and selecting the columns for alignment will work without problems. If the user now creates a new document, overwriting the old one, it will crash. If the new word document is created, without overwriting an old one, no errors occur.

So the combination out of overwriting an existing document, there aren't any word processes running, and selecting columns for right alignment will crash. This is how I try to align the columns.

```
objTable.Columns(4).Select
Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphRight

objTable.Columns(5).Select
Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphRight

objTable.Columns(6).Select
Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphRight
```

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Thanks

€dit:
We have software, where a user can create a Word document. The word document loads a Word Template, in which a bookmark marks the location for creating the table. Before the table is created, the new document from the template will be saved on a network path. If there is already a document from that template, it should be overwritten. After saving the document for the first time and giving the right name, my method creates the table and fills it with content. The creating part will crash as soon as my method tries to align the columns(alignment-part in the code above) if there was a document created before. I took a look at the task manager there were no running word processes left after the first run. If a new word document is created, without overwriting an existing one, there are no problems with the alignment. So I guess the combination of overwriting an existing document and the alignment is responsible for the error.

€dit2 - My Code (I removed unneccessary lines of code like variable declaration):

```
'That is kind of strange, because even though it should be nothing it  skipped that part - But if it tries to use the existing word instance - it crashes with the 462 - remote-server-computer is not available.   
If app is Nothing Then
        Set app = New Word.Application  
        Exit Function
End If
Set document = app.Documents.Add(Template:=Template, NewTemplate:=False, DocumentType:=0)
Dim settings As settings
settings = exportWord (document,...)


Private Function exportWord (oDoc As Word.Document,  ...) As settings
On Error GoTo Err_WordExport
Dim sets As settings
With sets
.export = False
End With
exportWord  = sets
Dim objRange As Word.Range
Dim objTable As Word.Table
With oDoc
    Set objRange = .Bookmarks("tbl").Range
    .Tables.Add objRange, positionen.Count + 1, 6
    Set objTable = .Bookmarks("tbl").Range.Tables(1)
End With
With objTable
    With .Rows(1)
        .Cells(1).Range.Text = ""
        .Cells(2).Range.Text = ""
        .Cells(3).Range.Text = ""
        .Cells(4).Range.Text = ""
        .Cells(5).Range.Text = ""
        .Cells(6).Range.Text = ""
        .Cells(1).Range.Font.Bold = True
        .Cells(2).Range.Font.Bold = True
        .Cells(3).Range.Font.Bold = True
        .Cells(4).Range.Font.Bold = True
        .Cells(5).Range.Font.Bold = True
        .Cells(6).Range.Font.Bold = True
    End With
End With
Dim i As Long
i = 2
For Each ItemPos In Positionen
'fill the content
Next ItemPos
With objTable.Rows(1).Borders(wdBorderBottom)
    .Visible = True
    .LineStyle = wdLineStyleDouble
End With
objTable.Columns(4).Select
Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphRight
objTable.Columns(5).Select
Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphRight
objTable.Columns(6).Select
Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphRight
objTable.Columns.AutoFit
oDoc.SaveAs2 pathToSave
    
With sets
   .export = True
   .PathToFile = pathToSave
End With
    
exportWord = sets
Set objTable = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Why does the document load a Word Template? If it is an actual Word template (.dotx, .dotm) the document should be created from it at the outset.

Comment: "If there is already a document from that template, it should be overwritten" - if there is an existing file with the same name it will undoubtedly get overwritten, regardless of what "template" the original file was created from. The only exception would be if there is a file locking issue. Have you checked for that?

Comment: If your code is crashing when it tries to select a column the most common cause would be that the table includes horizontally merged cells. Have you checked for that?

Comment: @TimothyRylatt thanks for your answer, there shouldn't be any merged cells. I added the code above.

Comment: Step through your code line by line and identify on which line the error occurs. That will give you a better idea of what is causing the problem.

Comment: I know on which line the error occurs. But I am not sure why.  It occurs on the column alignment part.  This is why I thought the problem is in context with the selection. Is there a way for me to select explicit the column in word? Maybe it didn't get the difference between the word document and the executing Microsoft Access while selecting.

Comment: The strange thing is that it crashes with Error 462 - remote server machine not found, which I can't explain to myself, because of the objTable, the document and the word.Application is closed and set explicitly to nothing. So there shouldn't be any running instances left. But if I debug my code and the code checks if the word instance is nothing it skips the part. if it then tries to use the "existing" instance - it crashes as well with 462.

Comment: Found a solution. I shouldn't use Selection without the Word instance. app.Selection.Paragraph... was the fix for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid selecting the columns by looping through the cells. You can also simplify your code as below:

```
Set objTable = oDoc.Tables.Add(oDoc.Bookmarks("tbl").Range, Positionen.Count + 1, 6)
With objTable
    Dim wdCell As Word.Cell
    With .Rows(1).Borders(wdBorderBottom)
        .Visible = True
        .LineStyle = wdLineStyleDouble
    End With
    For Each wdCell In .Rows(1).Cells
        With wdCell.Range
            .Text = ""
            .Font.Bold = True
        End With
    Next wdCell
    Dim colIndex As Long
    For colIndex = 4 To 6
        For Each wdCell In .Columns(colIndex).Cells
            wdCell.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphRight
        Next wdCell
    Next colIndex
End With
```

You can refine this even further simply by adding a 2 row table into the template with the formatting already applied. Then all you need is:

```
Set objTable = oDoc.Bookmarks("tbl").Range.Tables(1)
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To positionen - 1
    objTable.Rows.Add
Next i
```